# Primes in arithmetic progressions in Sagemath

Tags: primes, sage

I am in need of finding prime numbers in arithmetic progression

80218110*n+8021749, n=1 to 100,000

I was told that using Sage would be a good option, since my computer is old.  I happen to be new to Sage and I haven't found it to solve my problem, I guess it shouldn't be difficult, does anyone have a good reference for printing primes in arithmetic progressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SageMath is based on Python, and Python provides a syntax which should be comfortable for mathematicians:

```
[80218110*n + 8021749 for n in range(100)]
```

`range(100)` is the ordered set `0, 1, 2, ..., 99`, and so the previous line evaluates `80218110*n + 8021749` for these values of `n`. We can also test whether the entries are prime:

```
INPUT: [80218110*n+8021749 for n in range(100) if (80218110*n+8021749).is_prime()]
OUTPUT: 
[8021749,
 489330409,
 569548519,
 970639069,
 1050857179,
 1131075289,
 1772820169,
 2093692609,
 2173910719,
 3136528039,
 3617836699,
 4660672129,
 4740890239,
 5382635119,
 6425470549,
 7067215429,
 7227651649,
 7548524089]
```

You can of course make the argument to `range` larger, but maybe it's not a good idea to print the whole list.

```
INPUT: len([80218110*n+8021749 for n in range(100000) if (80218110*n+8021749).is_prime()])
OUTPUT: 15273
```

(`len` returns the length of the list.) Producing this list is pretty quick, at least on my computer:

```
INPUT: %time L = [80218110*n+8021749 for n in range(100000) if (80218110*n+8021749).is_prime()]
OUTPUT CPU times: user 94.6 ms, sys: 1.13 ms, total: 95.8 ms
Wall time: 95.5 ms
```

(`ms` is milliseconds.)